# Setting up application server

Tags: jboss

I want to know sites which can allow me to deploy my jboss server and mysql. I am looking for  very cheap rates. I also came across sites like godaddy.com which offer very cheap web hosting plans. But do they really allow you to host your jboss application server. if not where can I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check Super Java Host at  http://www.superjavahost.com

They look pretty cheap...

Answer (score 0):

Check Astrahosting.com

[www.astrahosting.com](http://www.astrahosting.com/)